# PHP decode JSON from Android

Tags: php, arrays, json

I post a JSON from Android to PHP:

```
{"0":{"nome":"name","cf":"0101","address":"STREET 123"},"1":{"codice":"123","nome":"ACQUA","quantita":"3"},"2":{"codice":"123","nome":"ACQUA","quantita":"3"}}
```

In php i need to get user info always `0` (nome, cf and address) after this i need a while for getting dynamic element 1,2,3,4 etc etc (in while) always codice, nome and quantita but i have tried some code in php like:

```
$string = {"0":{"nome":"name","cf":"0101","address":"STREET 123"},"1":{"codice":"123","nome":"ACQUA","quantita":"3"},"2":{"codice":"123","nome":"ACQUA","quantita":"3"}};

$string = json_encode($string);

$nome = json_decode ($string, true);

echo $nome[0]->nome; //for single user info
```

but result is always white page

Comment: Well, turn on error reporting because `$string = {` is most certainly a syntax error at minimum.

Comment: Yes error_reporting is on and no error in page =)

Comment: @MarcusJ.Kennedy `{}` is alternate syntax for creating associative arrays in PHP.

Comment: @Barmar How do you enable it? What PHP version?

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong.

Comment: Anyways, once you fix `$string = {` then change `echo $nome[0]->nome;` into `echo $nome[0]['nome'];` since you passed in `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode()`

Comment: What's the point of encoding and decoding?

Comment: It should be `$string = [ "0" => [ "nome" => "name", "cf" => "0101", ...`

Comment: You need to learn how to run code in a debugger. Most IDEs allow doing that, so do some online research. Further, you can run PHP code from the commandline, which is much better than running it in a webserver, because it eliminates any influence from the browser and webserver. Lastly, using those skills, you should try to extract a [mcve] from your problem code, because that should have given you the answer right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in the code...

```
$string = '{"0":{"nome":"name","cf":"0101","address":"STREET 123"},"1":{"codice":"123","nome":"ACQUA","quantita":"3"},"2":{"codice":"123","nome":"ACQUA","quantita":"3"}}';

//$string = json_encode($string);

$nome = json_decode ($string, true);

echo $nome[0]['nome']; //for single user info
```

The first line needs single quotes round it.

The `json_encode()` isn't needed as it's already JSON.

The last line needs to use `['nome']` as it's using arrays (by using true as the second parameter to `json_decode()`)

Comment: Thanks so much =)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, I assume this is a test prior to trying to link in the post from the App.